Is it absolutely necessary to reimage my Windows 11 machine because PCW.SYS has caused a BSOD?
Five months ago, I got a new desktop PC. My previous PC, which I got used 9 years ago, was giving out. It's an HP desktop with Windows 11 Enterprise installed, with an i9 processor.
However, it hasn't been a smooth experience. I've experienced with two or three blue screens of death. After the second one I decided to start tracking the BSOD.
Today I got another BSOD. I took a picture of the BSOD using my phone. The BSOD clearly shows that PCW.SYS caused the BSOD with a stop code of ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY. I shared this with my IT folks. Their solution was to reimage my machine!
I've got to admit that I'm shocked by this suggestion. They think I might inadvertently corrupt this with some download. I'm asking how in heck can that happen when I don't even have administrative privileges on my machine? This comes across more like they don't want to take the time to determine what's wrong and attempt to fix it. Their attitude is it is impossible to fix any issue caused by PCW.SYS, so the machine must be reimaged.
Is that correct? If PCW.SYS is corrupt, is it impossible to fix it? And how in heck could PCW.SYS have been corrupted?

Instead of a less than useful screenshot of the BSOD use WinDBG to analyze the memory dump and post that instead. If this isn’t your system, you should let your Administrator, handle the problem and avoid posting the information i requested, which is required, to help diagnose the problem. CrowdStrike literally involved a corrupt system file. PCW.SYS could easily become corrupt but it probably isn’t and the underlying problem likely is a hardware problem

There are tools built into Windows to repair the operating system. Have you tried SFC and DISM, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e ? Please edit the question to show the results. Alternatively, one can download the Windows 11 ISO and reinstall, keeping files, which is usually fairly safe (though I'd recommend making a drive image first, just in case).

So yes, your suspicions about your IT department are valid; in modern fleet management, no systems should be special, and any one that is, is techdebt awaiting resolution. They have likely built substantial infrastructure for policy orchestration,  application install/updates, user files, etc, for the specific purpose of making particular systems disposable. Why bother with the lengthy and error prone process of troubleshooting a deep system issue, when  you can just reimage or swap out the system? Thats just the way it is these days.

I was advised to run the following at an elevated command line: - Dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth. I'm not familiar with DISM, so I looked it up. I came across this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism?view=windows-11 The Limitations section at the link makes me wonder if my machine's DISM is too old?

Did you attempt to run it? It's unlikely to be the wrong version.

I did not. OK, I'll run it.
